# How to have Xamarin library project reference another library project

Tags: xamarin, visual-studio-mac

I have created a solution in Xamarin (Visual Studio for Mac) that has:

```
MyGame (solution)
> MyGame
> MyGame.Droid
> MyGame.IOS
> MyLibrary   <= this contains additional code to be used by MyGame
```

The odd thing is that if I open MyGame.Droid or MyGame.IOS there is a references folder where, for example, the MyGame project is referenced.

But, when I open up MyGame there is no References folder.

How do I add a reference in MyGame to MyLibrary?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the new project reference `MyLibrary` to both `MyGame.Droid` and `MyGame.IOS` projects.

It seems you've created a `Xamarin.Forms` project and then created a `.NET Standard` library project. By default `Xamarin.Forms` create a `Shared` project which means it is shared between `MyGame.Droid` and `MyGame.IOS` and whenever you build the Droid it becomes to be a part of the droid project and opposite for the iOS project.

As an alternative, you can convert your Shared project to the `.NET Standard` and then you will be able to add required references.

Comment: The solution I created was a "Native App (IOS, Android) Multiplatform -> App)... is there an easy way to convert a Shared project to a .Net Standard project... or just manually recreate it?... Also is there a way to determine what kind of project a project is?

Comment: there is no tool to migrate `shared` -> `.net standard` and an easy way to check is the project is `shared` is open its references. If it doesn't have the references folder - it's a shared project. You can recreate the project using the `.net standard` template and move all files there, it should be still compilable as long as API coverage with `.net standard 2.0` is pretty good.